# Why is there an $\alpha$ in the rule header of an inference rule?

Tags: logic

[image: statement]

**My Question is:** what is the first $\alpha$ in the two interference rules used for? The up-arrow is defined as 'nand'. I mean the first $\alpha$ before the comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *inference rule* is a rule licensing to derive from some *premises* $\varphi_1, \ldots \varphi_n$ a *conclusion* $\psi$.

An example is *modus ponens* :

> from the premises : $\alpha$ and $\alpha \to \beta$, derive : $\beta$.

It is often formalized in the form :

> $$\frac{\alpha \quad \quad \alpha \to \beta}{\beta}.$$

---

In your example, the rule :

> > $$\frac{\alpha \quad \quad \alpha \uparrow \beta}{\beta}$$

has the *premises* : $\alpha$ and $\alpha \uparrow \beta$ and the *conclusion* : $\beta$ and you have to check if the rule is correct (or *sound*).

We say that a set of inference rules, i.e. a *proof system*, is *sound* iff they are truth preserving: if all its undischarged assumptions are true then its conclusion is true also; that is, the conclusion is a logical consequence of the undischarged assumptions.

Thus, to check if the rule is correct, you have to consider the truth-table for [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) and check if it is true that :

> if $\alpha$ and $\alpha \uparrow \beta$ are true, also $\beta$ is.

Comment: so the a at the beginning just says that a is true?

Comment: The $\alpha$ at the beginning (indeed, everything above the line) are premises.   You can write it there whether or not it is true.

Comment: Sorry again to nit-pick on your very nice answers, Mauro.  But I'm not sure about the account of "soundness" of an inference rule given above.  In particular, what do you mean by "with it we can derive..."?  E.g., what does this mean in the case of discharge rules like conditional proof or existential quantification?  (Or structural rules like monotonicity?)  Doesn't it make soundness a "holistic" property of the system, rather than a property of individual rules?

Comment: Perhaps a notion of "soundness" appropriate to inference rules is this.  Say that a proof is valid if its conclusion is a logical consequence of its premises.  Regard a rule as a mapping from proofs to proofs.  Then: a rule is sound if it preserves validity.  One can now say that a system of rules is sound if each of the rules is sound; this yields (by induction on proofs) the usual metalogical meaning of "soundness" that every proof is valid.